# Kubuntu 16.10 tearing issues

Tags: kubuntu, kde, tearing

After installing Nvidia drivers on the new Kubuntu release (16.10) I'm having issues with general screen tearing (moving windows around, scrolling in the browser etc.)

I'm using GTX 960.

Are there any settings I could change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Graphic tearing is a widespread complaint about nvidia. I have not solved it in a Dell precision 5510, despite trying about 20 fixes. On the laptop itself, tearing is not horrible. On external monitor, it is awful. I get weird pie shaped tares.

If you google this, you will see this is not a Kubuntu problem. It is an Nvidia problem.

Things to try

Run nvidia-settings, find power setting and change to high performance.

Many posts will say set "Vblank", but that option disappeared in new version.

Kubuntu settings, under devices, has settings. Make sure compositor is on. It has buttons to turn.